# d3.js and loading data with special characters

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a simple graphic (bars) using with help of the d3.js library in which I represent the salaries of different job positions for every country. I am loading the data into js and I am encountering a problem.

The top row contains data like France (€)   Switzerland (CHF)   UK (£).

```
d3.tsv("operations.txt", function(error, data) { console.log(data) ; } )
```

When the data is loaded via the d3.tsv(...) method , in the console the keys are shown like France (�) ,  Switzerland (�) ,  UK (�).

I am sure that you can have Euro signs and Pound signs as part of a string in Javascript , but somehow in this parsing the symbols get lost.

Any suggestions on how I should tackle this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is probably encoded in [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15), a [custom parser](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#arbitrary-delimiters) will let you use a non-UTF8 file. Try :

```
var tsv = d3.dsv("\t", "text/tab-separated-values; charset=ISO-8859-15");
tsv("operations.txt", function(error, data) { console.log(data) ; } )
```

Comment: @Mg Did that help or was it something else?

Comment: Sorry about the big delay , i got sidetracked by another project. Couldn't come back to it until now! Above all I would like to thank you for your valuable answer.  That charset did not work, only worked with the pound sign! After a few tweaks I finally made it work  being  **ISO-8859-1**  the correct encoding . Again thank you so much